# Surface Area of a $p$-norm Sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, volume, spheres

There are many various ways to derive the formula for the volume of a $p$-norm ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$V_{n,p,R}=\frac{(2\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{p}))^n}{\Gamma(1+\frac{n}{p})}R^n$$

And I found many articles who use this to find the surface area (of $n-1$ dimensions) of the boundary sphere for $p=2$, using $\int_0^R S_{n,\color{red}2,r}\text{d}r=V_{n,\color{red}2,R}$ and concluding that $S_{n,\color{red}2,r}=\frac{\text{d}V_{n,\color{red}2,R}}{\text{d}r}$. This seems very intuative and does in-fact work.

My question is, how come this can't be generalized for arbitrary $p$? You would think that $p$-norm balls can also be divided into shells and by the same process achieve

$$S_{n,p,R}=\frac{(2\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{p}))^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{p})}pR^{n-1}$$

However, I found no articles doing this, and did find some sources which state there probably isn't any closed form for the surface area.

Comment: where can I find references for the formula for $V(R)$? I have found some articles that deduce it for the unit ball, but I'd like to see it for the more general case. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The point is that
$$ \frac{d}{dR} V(R) = A(R) $$
works for the Euclidean norm because if $A$ and $B$ are balls with respect to such norm, $A+B$ still is a ball with respect to such norm. Such fact allows to derive a short proof of the isoperimetric inequality (in arbitrary dimension!) through the [Brunn-Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem), for instance. The same does not hold for different norms. Let us consider $n=2$ and the $4$-norm. The length of the curve $\{(x,y):x^4+y^4=1\}$ can be computed as
$$ 4\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{x^6}{(1-x^4)^{3/2}}}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{-3/4}\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{3/2}}{(1-x)^{3/2}}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+x^{3/2}}\,dx}{x^{3/4}(1+x)^{5/4}} $$
which is a highly non-elementary integral, $\approx 7.017697943564$. The enclosed area is a bit better:
$$ 4\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^4)^{1/4}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^{-3/4}(1-x)^{1/4}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2\sqrt{\pi}} $$
thanks to Euler's Beta function. In higher dimensions it only gets worse.

Comment: 1. It's not quite clear to me how does the fact that the property you said indicates about the ability to divide the ball into shells. Care to elaborate?

Comment: 2. By the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality we get that if $||x||\leq a$ and $||y||\leq b$ so $||x+y||\leq a+b$, even in $p$-norm. So... how come it's not true that $A+B$ is also a ball of such norm?

Comment: @Theorem: to state $\frac{dV}{dR}=A$ we need something stronger than the triangle inequality, we need that the evolute of a ball still is a ball with respect to the same norm. It works for the Euclidean norm, not for other norms.